# How to use for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

Ok, so i have an unordered list and it has two items. Now in my javascript i am trying to add event listener to these items so that a CSS class can be applied to them once clicked. here is the code. can anyone fill the missing part in here.Thanks

html part:-

```
<body>
    <h3>Simple Add/Remove Task</h3>
    <h4>To do List</h4>
    <ul>
        <div>
            <li class="todos">Wake up</li>
            <li class="todos">Study</li>
        </div>

    <div>
        <button>Delete</button><br>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Js part:-

```
    var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("todos");


for (var i = 0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        
    })
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Please specify.

Comment: `this.classList.add("yourClassNameHere");`?

Comment: your HTML is invalid: `<ul>` can contain `<li>` children only.

Comment: @Kosh It can also contain [`script` and `template` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add or toggle the desired class with [`classList.add()` or `classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Also (FYI):

- Headings should not be used because of the way they style the text
  within them. As with everything else in HTML, they are semantic. You
  shouldn't have an `h4` unless you want a new sub-section to an `h3`,
  which you wouldn't have unless it was a sub-section of an `h2` an so
  on. You can (and should) do your formatting with CSS, not HTML.
- It is also invalid to put a `div` directly inside of a `ul`. Only
  `li`, `script`, or `template` elements can be children of a `ul` or
  `ol`.
- [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".todos");

for (var i = 0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.toggle("active");  // each click toggles the use of the class
    });
    
    // While looping over the bullets, search for the button within each
    // and set up a click handler for when the delete button gets clicked
    // .closest() will look for the nearest ancestor that matches the selector.
    listItems[i].querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.closest(".todos").remove();
    });
}
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; }
h2 { font-size: 1em; }

.active { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<h1>Simple Add/Remove Task</h1>
<h2>To do List</h2>
<ul>
  <li class="todos">Wake up <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li class="todos">Study <button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, so thanks for a detailed answer. i want the buttons next to both li. Should i make two divs and put ul in first one and buttons in second one? As the next function i will be adding is to delete li by delete buttons next to them.

Comment: @new2coding That really is a different question, but I have updated my answer to show that you just need to move the buttons inside of the `li` elements and set up a `click` handler on them. Please consider marking this as "the" answer and up vote all helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in js to change the class:

```
listItems[i].className = 'cssClass';
```

and then make some 'cssClass' css. Unless you want to make the css created in js, in which case you would do this beforehand:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { color: green; }';
```

Comment: The `style` element doesn't need a `type="text/css"` attribute any more.

Answer (score 0):

Use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over the elements.

Use the [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the selected element.

Use [classList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add a class to an element

```js
var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("todos");

for (let listItem of listItems) {
    listItem.addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.currentTarget.classList.add('selected')
    })
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h3>Simple Add/Remove Task</h3>
    <h4>To do List</h4>
    <ul>
      <li class="todos">Wake up</li>
      <li class="todos">Study</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Why `event.target` instead of just `this`?

Comment: @Scott Marcus Personal preference, I find `event.target` easier to understand. There is also often confusion about the scope of `this`, especially when it comes to arrow functions.

Comment: @Scott Marcus actually `event.currentTarget` is a better choice here. Reflected that in my answer ;).

Comment: In this case, there would be no difference between target and currentTarget because no propagation of the event is utilized here.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: There’s no safe or sorry to worry about here. If there were, event.target would be the better choice, but the best choice would be ‘this’, which is what I suggested in the first place.